# Convergence of fibonacci quotient $\frac{f_n}{f_{n+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, proof-verification, fibonacci-numbers

I know that $\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}}$ converges against $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

The question i want to to ask you is if the following conclusion is correct, I mean i know that if we have two convergent sequences in the (de-)nominator we can swap them around and the limit will swap as well, after the rules of sequence - convergence. But things seem to be not as easy as that with sequences like the fibonacci quotient.

We have

$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

We also know that

$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}}\frac{f_{n}}{f_{n+1}} = 1$

because $f_n$ and $f_{n+1}$ both cancel out.

Because $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n * b_n = a*b$ We have

$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_{n}}\frac{f_{n}}{f_{n+1}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} * x = 1 \implies $ $ x = \frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}} $

Comment: Another way is to observe that $\frac{f_n}{f_{n+1}}=\frac1{f_{n+1}/f_n}$, so $$\lim_n\frac{f_n}{f_{n+1}}= \frac1{\lim_n(f_{n+1}/f_n)}= \frac1{\varphi}=\frac2{1+\sqrt5}\;.$$ Rationalizing the denominator gives you $\frac{-1-\sqrt5}2=\varphi-1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've made a mistake $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}\cdot\frac{F_{n+1}}{F_n}=1$ hence you have that $$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\cdot x=1\\\ x=\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{5}}$$

Comment: Yeah that is what i meant. Thank you.